# Finding a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is neither open nor closed

Tags: real-analysis

Find a bounded, continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\mathbb{R})$ is neither open nor closed?

Comment: I see no questions, just an order. Unless you contribute some of your ideas to the post, this is likely to be closed.

Comment: @rschwieb Not a question: "Derive the quadratic formula." $\mapsto$ Question: "Derive the quadratic formula?"

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos ERight :) What could would a question mark be if it didn't transform any string of letters into a question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take $f(x):=e^{-x^2}$: it's a continuous bounded function on the real line, and $f(\Bbb R)=(0,1]$, which is neither open nor closed.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined as $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$. You have that $f(\mathbb{R})=[0,1)$ which is neither open nor closed.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f(x) = \arctan(x^2)$. Then, $f(\mathbb{R}) = [0, \pi/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(x)$ to be 
$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{x^2}, \ x\not\in [-1,1],
\\
\\
\\
1 \ \ \  \ , x\in[-1,1]
\end{cases}
$.
Is $f$ continuous? Bounded? What is $f(\mathbb R)$?